# Copy Mapbox style to another account WITH tilesets it uses

Tags: mapbox

In Mapbox documentation, there is a simple way to copy a style from one account to another.

However, the copied style is still using the custom tilesets from the old account and I didn't find any way to transfer the tilesets together with the style. How do I do that?

Also, is there a way to export/download the custom tileset (that I uploaded a while ago and lost the source since) from my own account?

Comment: Same here. Have you found any solution?